# OpenAM Fedlet Single Sign Out

Tags: java, single-sign-on, openam

I have developed an application as SP using OpenAM fedlet. Single Sign on is working fine and Single Sign out also happening from Idp (Idp is SimpleSAMLPHP).

But Im facing one issue, when I have connected two SP's and do single sign out its successfully signed out from Idp but the local session for second SP

still exists and able to access the site even after logged out of Idp.

I assume that for each request in SP should validate whether valid session exists in Idp, but I'm unable to find how to do with OpenAM fedlet.

Can you please give me some valuable input to signout local session of SP when signout is happened from any other SP.

Regards
Arjun S

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using OpenAM but only OpenAM Fedlet you might be better of using Spring Security SAML extension as OpenAM Fedlet requires much more work than Spring Security SAML extension.

Comment: I did not understand what is mean by "much more work". Can you please clarify? If you have more details on wat kind of work to be done. Can you please list those here...